# My web service throwing exception:javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class [Ljava.lang.String; nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JAXB Marshalling Objects with java.lang.Object field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269494/jaxb-marshalling-objects-with-java-lang-object-field)

I am new in **Web Services**.I am trying to develop a service using **JAX-WS**.My **service signature** is like this.

```
@WebService
@MTOM
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface DocumentOperationService {
    @WebMethod
    Object[] getDocumentById(String strDocumentId);
}
```

but while running,at run time it's throwing an **Exception:**

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class [Ljava.lang.String; nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
```

I am not able to identify the problem.Can anybody suggest what's wrong in this.

Comment: If you had done a Google search with your exception the answer would have been in the first hit. -1 for no research.

Comment: I tried with Google also,but i am the beginner.So i haven't understand solution they replied.