# How to retrieve the values from the service which is returning List<Object> using jax-ws

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

I have a service which returns the List, this object varies depends on different scenario.

Can somebody suggest me does jax-ws support this behaviour or do we have any alternative option.

Answer (score 0):

Since that JAX-WS use JAXB for serializate the objects, JAXB need to know the name of the type for marshall or unmarshall. In a standalone environment can [deal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269494/jaxb-marshalling-objects-with-java-lang-object-field) with this kind of things. However, when dealing with a list of objects, this becomes more complicated.

Moreover, each data type must be defined in the WSDL. The service client must be able to convert the response XML to the data type desired.

If you wish to return different lists of different type, the simplest is to use a wrapper for the response. e.g.

```
public class ResponseWrapper {
    private List<Audio> audios;
    private List<Video> videos;

    // setters and getters
}

@WebService
public class MediaStore {

    @Inject
    AudioService audioService;
    @Inject
    VideoService videoService;

    @WebMethod
    public ResponseWrapper getCollections(String artistId) {
        ResponseWrapper response = new ResponseWrapper();
        response.setAudios(audioService.getAudios(artistId));
        response.setAudios(videoService.getVideos(artistId));
        return response;
    }
}
```

Another way would be to work directly with [SOAP messages](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/SAAJ4.html), but you could avoid doing so.